# How do I replace the default action of Tab Key to move to next HTML textbox with my own JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

Take this HTML code, if you place your cursor on the 1st text-box, and then press Tab Key. The cursor will automatically jump to the 2nd text-box.

```
Box1:
<textarea id='box' cols='60' rows='10'></textarea>

Box2:
<textarea id='box' cols='60' rows='10'></textarea>
```

I need to replace this default action of switching to the next textbox with execution of JavaScript function I've defined. Let's say: instead of switching textboxes execute function that writes 'a' on the the 1st text-box upon pressing Tab inside the box.

Any idea how I can make this happen?

Comment: You can call the `preventDefault` method on the event object when handling the press of the tab key. But I strongly caution against doing this, as those who can only easily navigate your webpage using a keyboard will then not be able to do it, or at least not in the expected way that should work universally across all webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to listen to the `keydown` event (tested the others they do not work for this specific case). From there you need to check if tab was pressed. Then you would need to prevent the default from happening and finally execute your custom logic. In the example down below the default functionality of tab is only then overwritten if the first textarea is focussed.

```
<textarea id="box1"></textarea>
<textarea id="box2"></textarea>
```

```
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 9) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.value += "a"; // adding a to textarea (your example)
  }
})
```